# useTransition is not working with my code - TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I'm using React-Spring useTransition and getting error :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useSpring, useTransition, animated } from 'react-spring'


function MyApp() {

  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: 'Item1' }, { id: 2, text: 'Item2' }
  ]);


  const transition = useTransition(items, item => item.id, {
    from: { opacity: 0, marginLeft: -100, marginRight: 100 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {transition.map(({ item, key, props }) =>
          <animated.div key={key} style={props}>{item.text}</animated.div>
        )}

      </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're installing react-spring without specifying a version, so you're probably getting v9 now. V9 has some breaking changes to it, which unfortunately are not reflected in the documentation. But do check out [this explanation.](https://aleclarson.github.io/react-spring/v9/breaking-changes/)

The long and short of it is that useTransition, is totally different now. Instead of mapping from transitions, transitions can be called as a function that will return a fragment that you can render. I edited your code a bit to reflect that:

```
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    { id: 1, text: "Item1" },
    { id: 2, text: "Item2" }
  ]);

  const transition = useTransition(items, {
    from: { opacity: 0, marginLeft: -100, marginRight: 100 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0 }
  });

  const fragment = transition((style, item) => {
    return <animated.div style={style}>{item.text}</animated.div>;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>{fragment}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Check out this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-goldberg-fzinf?file=/src/App.js) to play around with it. Because it's only transitioning when it's first rendered, you'll have to hit reload to see the item names slide in from the left.